# Algebraicity of a ratio of values of the Gamma function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The following ratio:

$$\frac{\Gamma(2/5)^3}{\pi\Gamma(1/5)}$$

has kept appearing in my research, and the only thing I know about its value is that it is $\cong 0.7567213$, whence the following two questions:

Is the value of this ratio an algebraic number?

What is the exact value of this ratio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This number is expected to be transcendental. [This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/344203/6506) gives a conceptual framework for studying the algebraicity of such $\Gamma$ ratios, and in fact a completely explicit criterion (which is only conjectural, when it comes to establishing transcendence).

Your number is equal to
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\Gamma(2/5)^3}{\Gamma(1/5)^2 \Gamma(4/5)}
\end{equation*}
up to multiplication by an algebraic number. This ratio is described by the vector of exponents $(-2,3,0,-1)$ and the criterion there is not met for $u=2$. In fancy terms, the Bernoulli distribution $B_1$ does not vanish on this vector.

Comment: ...which itself can be rewritten as $~\dfrac{B\bigg(\dfrac25,~\dfrac25\bigg)}{B\bigg(\dfrac15,~\dfrac15\bigg)}~.$